Issues with position_jitterdodge when changing jitter.width in ggplot2
When jitter.width = 0, the plot drawing goes well.
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(77)

a1 <- bind_rows(tibble(ID=factor(letters[1:15]), y=runif(15), TP="A", Grp=rep(c("C","P","Q"), 5)),
                tibble(ID=factor(letters[1:15]), y=runif(15), TP="B", Grp=rep(c("C","P","Q"), 5)),
                tibble(ID=factor(letters[1:15]), y=runif(15), TP="C", Grp=rep(c("C","P","Q"), 5)),
) %>% mutate(TP=factor(TP), Grp=factor(Grp))


a2 <- a1 %>% arrange(ID, TP, Grp)

pj <- position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=0,
                           jitter.height = 0,
                           dodge.width = 0.75,
                           seed=9)

pp4 <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x=TP, y=y, fill=Grp)) +
  geom_boxplot(data=a1, alpha=0.2, outlier.colour = NA, width =0.75) +
  geom_point(data=a2, aes(colour=Grp, group=interaction(ID,Grp)),
             position = pj) +  
  geom_line(data=a2, aes(colour=Grp, group=interaction(ID,Grp)),
             position = pj)


pp4

Here is the plot:

But when I change jitter.width to 1, the plot cannot align smoothly. Here is the corresponding plot:

I'm not sure why this is happening. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.
